# How does my phase portrait fit with my differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation
$$ 0.25x'+0.0001x''+0.0001x=\sin(2000\pi t)$$ with initial conditions $x(0)=0, x'(0)=0$.

WolframAlpha plots the solution to this as

[image: WolframAlpha solution]

but if I plot it on [this website](https://aeb019.hosted.uark.edu/pplane.html) using the following system of equations:

[image: input]

I get this phase portrait which I don't see how relates to my solution.

[image: phase portrait]

Comment: In the first case, the axes are (t,x), in the second case, the axes are (x,y)...

Comment: "This page plots a system of differential equations of the form dx/dt = f(x,y), dy/dt = g(x,y)." So you can't have $t$ on the right-hand side! (The concept of phase portrait makes no sense for non-autonomous systems.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh well that's not good... I guess I'm not quite sure what I thought a phase portrait was then. Thanks for clearing this up for me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the ODE

$$
0.25x'+0.0001x''+0.0001x=\sin(2000\pi t)
$$

or normalizing

$$
x''+2500x'+x=10000\sin(2000\pi t)
$$

we can construct the first order equivalent system

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = -2500x_2-x_1 -10000\sin(2000\pi t)
}
$$

Considering the corresponding homogeneous/autonomous system

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = -2500x_2-x_1
}
$$

we can draw for the autonomous part, a phase portrait as follows:

[image]

From this phase portrait we can conclude that the autonomous system is stable to initial conditions or in other words, given $\{x_1(0), x_2(0)\}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ the system evolves to the origin.